# Can't start Software Center or Software Updater in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: software-center, update-manager

Several days ago, I started seeing a red circle with a white line stating :
"**The was a problem when checking for the updates**"

When I select "Show Updates" in that menu, I see the following in the syslog:

```
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: Traceback (most recent call last):
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 38, in <module>
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: from UpdateManager.UpdateManager import UpdateManager
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UpdateManager.py", line 57, in <module>
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: from .MetaReleaseGObject import MetaRelease
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/MetaReleaseGObject.py", line 25, in <module>
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: from .Core.MetaRelease import MetaReleaseCore
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py", line 25, in <module>
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: import apt
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: from apt.package import Package
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/package.py", line 42, in <module>
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: import apt.progress.text
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: ImportError: No module named 'apt.progress'
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: Error in sys.excepthook:
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: Traceback (most recent call last):
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: from apport.report import Report
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: import apport.fileutils
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: import apt
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: from apt.package import Package
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/package.py", line 42, in <module>
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: import apt.progress.text
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: ImportError: No module named 'apt.progress'
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: Original exception was:
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: Traceback (most recent call last):
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 38, in <module>
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: from UpdateManager.UpdateManager import UpdateManager
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UpdateManager.py", line 57, in <module>
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: from .MetaReleaseGObject import MetaRelease
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/MetaReleaseGObject.py", line 25, in <module>
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: from .Core.MetaRelease import MetaReleaseCore
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py", line 25, in <module>
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: import apt
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: from apt.package import Package
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/package.py", line 42, in <module>
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: import apt.progress.text
May 23 10:00:05 scorpio gnome-session[2032]: ImportError: No module named 'apt.progress'
```

I get similar errors (about the apt.progress Python module) when running Software Center.

I've seen lots of issues with the Software Updater while searching for answers but none of them seem to address this issue.

This started happening after I clicked "**upgrade**" in the updater but then did not upgrade.  I also recently installed mysql using `apt-get` from the command line.  I'm well versed at commoand line (Solaris, OSX) and intermediate in Linux.  I'm not sure what I need to do with Python to fix this.  I recently migrated my day to day workflow from OSX -> Ubuntu and loath trying to re-install and reconfigure everything if I don't have to.

Comment: Alright. In that case I'll convert my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a package was corrupted and misses some important files. You need to reinstall the packages `python3-apt` and, just to be safe, `ubuntu-desktop`:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop python3-apt
```

To detect corrupted packages early and even automatically in the future you can refer to “[Is there a Ubuntu sanity check?](/q/57704/175814)”.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!